# How to set DataNavigateUrlFormatString dynamically ? or How to eval Page.User.Identity.Name on a webpage?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, eval

I am building a GridView which can download songs. So I use a hyperlink fileld and use **DateNavigateUrlFormatString**.

E.G.

```
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/uploads/{0}"
```

Now,

I need to combine **Page.User.Identity.Name** into DateNavigateUrlFormatString

For example,

```
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/uploads/UserName/{0}" which  Page.User.Identity.Name depending on the user login.
```

I tried to access DataNavigateUrlFormatString from the code behind but I couldn't.
I tried to use Eval such as

```
      '~/uploads/" <%# Eval("Page.User.Identity.Name") %> /{0}'
```

this doesn't work as well.

Hope someone could point me out.

Thanks,

L

**FInal Solution**

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Play">
              <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl = '<%#    String.Format("~/UserUploads/{0}/",Page.User.Identity.Name)+ "/" + Eval("Song_Name")  %>' Text="Play" >
                    </asp:HyperLink>

                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You should add your "final solution" as an answer, and accept it instead of the wrong one from scartag

Comment: @Rich you didn't read the comments which showed the conversation we had after my answer? My answer led to the final solution. If you read his question you'll realize that he didn't explain in enough detail but my answer was able to guide him to his final solution. I will edit my answer to include his solution though. Just so its clear for whoever comes here looking.

Comment: I think that, on Stackoverflow, you are meant to edit your answer to be correct, so the question is easy to read for newcomers, not preserve incorrect answers and the comment chain following on from them. Maybe you should edit your answer to look like the "final solution", rather than Laurence adding a second answer? That would preserve your rep, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: @Rich Ok .. Done. The initial answer was based on the incorrect info he provided though. You are right though, on editing the answer to show the correct/final solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataNavigateUrlFormatString expects the placeholder(s) to come from fields in the datasource of the control.

My suggestion is that since you already know the url you are trying to build you could set the NavigateUrl property of hyperlink control.

```
NavigateUrl =  '<%# String.Format("~/UserUploads/{0}/",Page.User.Identity.Name)+ "/" + Eval("Song_Name") %>'
```

Comment: I got this error when I tried to put that .. I am using HyperLinkField by the way .. any thoughts ? Parser Error Message: Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField does not have a DataBinding event.

Comment: @Laurence Nyein Can you change it to a TemplateColumn and add a LinkButton? that would work well as it has a databinding event and this code would easily work with it.

Comment: Right , now i change with HyperLink control .. it does not give me Parser Error anymore .. However, the url becomes /uploads/UserName/MrABC instead of /uploads/MrABC/a.mp3. The second one is the correct one. Any thoughts?

Comment: @LaurenceNyein is the "a.mp3" constant for all users? if it is you can just put "/a.mp3" after the "{0}"

Comment: Hi Scartag .. finally , this conbination gives me the result I wanted ... '<%# String.Format("~/UserUploads/{0}/",Page.User.Identity.Name)+ "/" + Eval("Song_Name")  %>' Thanks for your help ..